# Make a general working code with tables from Wiki

Tags: r

I am one the quest to make a general function for the Premier League table with data from Wiki. Down below is how the desired function should look like where read_prem_league(2020) will show the table from the desired year as a tibble.

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20XX–XX_Premier_League"

read_prem_league <- function(season){ }

`read_prem_league(2020)`

I have this function below that works for a single year. So what I'm trying to figure out is how to make the XX in the url to a "key" down below and then rename it so e.g. read_prem_league(2019) will generate table for the season ending in 2019.

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018–19_Premier_League"
page <- read_html(url)
premierleague <- html_table(prem[[5]])
prem <- html_elements(page, css = "table")

premierleague
```

**Moreover**

Thanks for the excellent answer. I've just one more query.

I have this dataset that I want to make a function aswell. Everything is almost similar except the link only contain one year in contrast to double year as in Premier League. **How do I build an URL for a given year as in this example?** Pretty hard to figure it out for an amateur.

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20XX_Men%27s_Ice_Hockey_World_Championships"

```
read_icehockey <- function(year){ }

read_icehockey(2016)
```

`Group A`

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Men%27s_Ice_Hockey_World_Championships"
page <- read_html(url)
championship <- html_table(hockey[[3]])
hockey <- html_elements(page, css = "table")

championship
```

I guess the function for icehockey should look something like this:

```
read_icehockey <- function(year) {
  
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>%
  paste0(year - 0, "-", substr(as.character(year), 4), "_Men%27s_Ice_Hockey_World_Championships") %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(3)
}
```

`read_icehockey(2016)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `paste0` and `substr` to build the url for a given year:

```r
library(rvest)

read_prem_league <- function(year) {
  
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>%
  paste0(year - 1, "-", substr(as.character(year), 3, 4), "_Premier_League") %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(5)
}

read_prem_league(2021)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 11
#>      Pos Team                   Pld     W     D     L    GF    GA GD      Pts
#>    <int> <chr>                <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int>
#>  1     1 Manchester City (C)     38    27     5     6    83    32 +51      86
#>  2     2 Manchester United       38    21    11     6    73    44 +29      74
#>  3     3 Liverpool               38    20     9     9    68    42 +26      69
#>  4     4 Chelsea                 38    19    10     9    58    36 +22      67
#>  5     5 Leicester City          38    20     6    12    68    50 +18      66
#>  6     6 West Ham United         38    19     8    11    62    47 +15      65
#>  7     7 Tottenham Hotspur       38    18     8    12    68    45 +23      62
#>  8     8 Arsenal                 38    18     7    13    55    39 +16      61
#>  9     9 Leeds United            38    18     5    15    62    54 +8       59
#> 10    10 Everton                 38    17     8    13    47    48 -1       59
#> 11    11 Aston Villa             38    16     7    15    55    46 +9       55
#> 12    12 Newcastle United        38    12     9    17    46    62 -16      45
#> 13    13 Wolverhampton Wande~    38    12     9    17    36    52 -16      45
#> 14    14 Crystal Palace          38    12     8    18    41    66 -25      44
#> 15    15 Southampton             38    12     7    19    47    68 -21      43
#> 16    16 Brighton & Hove Alb~    38     9    14    15    40    46 -6       41
#> 17    17 Burnley                 38    10     9    19    33    55 -22      39
#> 18    18 Fulham (R)              38     5    13    20    27    53 -26      28
#> 19    19 West Bromwich Albio~    38     5    11    22    35    76 -41      26
#> 20    20 Sheffield United (R)    38     7     2    29    20    63 -43      23
#> # ... with 1 more variable: `Qualification or relegation` <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I added a new question similar to the first one as I'm doing this for Icehockey aswell. Don't really now how to manage the URL with different years. Would be extremely happy if anyone could give some tips. :)

Comment: Try `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>% paste0(year, "_Men%27s_Ice_Hockey_World_Championships")`